# While loop to add 1 to filename if it already exists not working in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to create a bit of code to first check the content of a directory to see if a file exists and if it does, append a number to the filename. Unfortunately I can't get it to work at the moment, the php produces no errors but a new file is not created if one already exists. Here is my code atm:

```
$Scan_Name_Output =  "dirbuster_" . $workload["Scan_Name"] . "_output.txt"; 
$Check_Output = exec("ls " . $Output_Directory . " | grep -w " . $Scan_Name_Output);
$j = 1;

while (!empty($Check_Output))
{
    $Scan_Name_Output = $Scan_Name_Output . $j;
    $j++;
```

If I replace the while loop with an if statement, it works - so it's not the file paths or anything that are causing the problem. I've tried a fair few combinations but can't get it to work.

I have tried using file_exists() but it doesn't work - I think it's because I'm passing it variables that have been put through escapeshellarg(). As a result I think file_exists literally looks for /path/to/dir/'Report1.txt' - obviously 'Report1.txt' doesn't exist, Report1.txt does. This is why I was using exec and ls.

Thanks for any responses

Comment: Jingo, have you made sure it's not creating errors, displa_errors is usually off be default.  Try putting ini_set('display_errors',1); 
at the top of your file to make sure there are no errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has some nice functions built in to handle files. You should think about using [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) for example.

```
$basename =  "dirbuster_" . $workload["Scan_Name"] . "_output.txt";          
$Scan_Name_Output = $basename;
$j = 1;
while (file_exists($Scan_Name_Output)){
    $Scan_Name_Output = $basename . $j;
    $j++;
}
$ourFileHandle = fopen($Scan_Name_Output, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned in my original post, I will edit it to make it clear. I have tried file_exists() but it doesn't work - I think it's because I'm passing out variables that have been put through escapeshellarg(). As a result I think file_exists literally looks for /path/to/dir/'Report1.txt' - obviously 'Report1.txt' doesn't exist, Report1.txt does. This is why I was using exec and ls. Thanks for your response though!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$Scan_Name_Output =  "dirbuster_" . $workload["Scan_Name"] . "_output.txt";
if (file_exists($Scan_Name_Output))
{
    rename($Scan_Name_Output, $Scan_Name_Output . "1");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if you see my updated post you'll see why file_exists does not appear to be working for me. Cheers

Comment: also, this won't work if there are two files name report.txt and report.txt1 - it will just overwrite the report.txt1 file as there is no counter, will it not?

Comment: why don't u use trim() to remove the single quotes before passing to file_exists- you can do this: $Scan_Name_Output =  "dirbuster_" . trim($workload["Scan_Name"], "'") . "_output.txt";

Comment: If the second argument in trim() was not clear, it was the single quote that was given as the second argument (as you can specify which characters to be trimmed, read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: thanks - doing this does work but I had to remove the ' ' from two user supplied variables. By doing this am I not effectively just removing any sanitization from user supplied input? This was why I was looking for a solution to the original piece of code.